# Problem with Airprint server for iOS 6

Tags: debian, cups, apple, ios

I'm trying to set up Airprint server on Raspberry Pi under CUPS. I have done everything like in this tutorial: [Configuring the Raspberry Pi as an AirPrint server](http://rohankapoor.com/2012/06/configuring-the-raspberry-pi-as-an-airprint-server/).

Then I have done this:  [Linux Airprint Server for iOS6 devices](http://blog.mornati.net/2012/09/22/linux-airprint-server-for-ios6-devices/) to make it compatible with iOS 6 devices, but iPad with iOS 6 can't see it. It only can be seen by another CUPS server on the local network.

Any ideas?